# If $g=\int dr\, F(\rho_e,\rho_p,\gamma_{ee},\gamma_{pp},\gamma_{ep})$, what is $\frac{\delta g}{\delta \rho_e}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have read the following equation in somewhere which I can't understand it, can anyone  explain it?
If we have

$$
g=\int dr \, F(\rho_e,\rho_p,\gamma_{ee},\gamma_{pp},\gamma_{ep}) \tag{1}
$$
and  $\gamma_{ab}=\nabla\rho_a \; . \nabla \rho_b $ then

$$
\frac{\delta g}{\delta \rho_e}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial \rho_e}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial \gamma_{ee}}\frac{\partial \gamma_{ee}}{\partial\rho_{e}}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial \gamma_{ep}}\frac{\partial \gamma_{ep}}{\partial \rho_{e}}
= \frac{\partial F}{\partial \rho_e}+2\frac{\partial F}{\partial \gamma_{ee}}\nabla \rho_e \; . \nabla_e+\frac{\partial F}{\partial \gamma_{ep}}\nabla \rho_{p}\; . \nabla_e \tag{3}
$$
I want to know how can we reach to $(3)$? and what does mean a single $\nabla_e$ in it?

Comment: Without notation or context, the question is a bit ambiguous. You should add the context or clarify the participating objects at least. The notation $\nabla_{e}$ could come from Levi-Civita notation, for example.

Comment: @user1027216 Sorry but this is all that I know! There was no more information in the source also.